# Loop over all children and subchildren of a space Xwiki

Tags: velocity, confluence, xwiki, confluence-macros

We are trying to migrate from Confluence and the macro `time` is not recognized by Xwiki when importing spaces.
So I’m trying to create an application to change each macro like this one `<time datetime="2021-01-29" class="date-past">29 Jan. 2021</time\>` into an Xwiki date/time format.

I’m having trouble with the first step: going through all the children and sub-children in the space to inspect their content.
Do you have any ideas on how to do this? Or a better solution to fix the missing time macro? I’m fairly new to Xwiki…

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use XWiki's scripting capabilities (https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/) and the exposed API (https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/APIGuide/) in order to process each document.

Regarding the particular Confluence macro, it's not clear to me what it does (i.e. it just displays a date in some way or is it a date picker?) and which would be the XWiki equivalent, if any. Either way, you would have to transform it into something that XWiki can understand, possibly even a macro you may have to create for this particular exercise.